# Finding coordinates of position given three coordinates and distances: 3D

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I'm hoping to determine the x, y, z coordinates of a 4th position (D) given the coordinates of three other positions and their distances: $A(0.25, 0.25, 0.25), B(0.4663, 0, 0.25)$, and $C (0.3912, 0.1558, 0.3796)$.

$AD = 3.3285, BD = 3.3399, CD = 2.21$. Easiest to show with a picture, but I don't have enough rep. on the site to post a picture yet, so here's a Google Drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v43WHPkYHpWUFlOXdWS2I0VVE/view?pli=1):

[image]

Using the given angles, law of cosines, and distance formula gives me three nonlinear equations and three unknowns. Afraid I'm not seeing a way to either substitute or eliminate variables to solve for x, y, or z.

I tried this using Matlab's fsolve function. In editor:

`function F = myfun(x)`
`F = [(0.25-x(1))^2+(0.25-x(2))^2+(0.25-x(3))^2-3.3285^2; 
      (0.3912-x(1))^2+(0.1558-x(2))^2+(0.3796-x(3))^2-2.2124^2; 
      (0.4663-x(1))^2+(x(2))^2+(0.25-x(3))^2-3.3399^2];`

`end`

In the command window, initialize a guess for all 3 elements:

`x0 = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]` (Just an arbitrary guess)

`fsolve(@myfun, x0)`

This returns the error: "fsolve stopped prematurely because it exceeded the function evaluation limit." Unsure how to proceed.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you sure there will be "a solution" and not a locus of points for this problem? I feel it will be a circle.
Anyway one point is the point D that is in the same plane as the other three points. That should be easy to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It's quite possible that there are many solutions to this, where all the x, y, z combinations lie on a circle. 
However, I don't believe point D is in the same plane as the other 3. I'm afraid the rough sketch I've made doesn't show it properly.
ACD forms a triangle in one plane, but BCD forms a triangle in a different, bisecting plane. Or perhaps I've misunderstood your meaning.

Comment: no, it'll not lie in the same plane. The circle (or any other shape) will be in a different plane, of course

Comment: Let A is O, B is $\vec{i}$ and C is $x_c\vec{i}+y_c\vec{j}$.
Then $|AD|^2 = x_d^2 + y_d^2 + z_d^2, |BD|^2 = (x_d-1)^2 + y_d^2 + z_d^2, |CD|^2 = (x_d-x_c)^2 + (y_d-y_c)^2 + z_d^2$
From |AD| and |BD|, find $x_d$.
$\angle{ACD} = \alpha\implies cos(\alpha)=\frac{AC\cdot CD}{|AC||CD|} \implies x_cx_d+y_cy_d=K$
find $y_d$ from this. Find $z_d from |CD|$.
Seems to have only 4 solutions at max. I was wrong in thinking it would be a circle.
The assumption could be problematic - I hope there is some rotation, scaling and Translation that will do the trick. Also, the distances should be scaled properly.

Comment: Wait... if the above is feasible, then doing the same thing on the normal coordinated should work - maybe unwieldy but possible.